# Procesar String en formato XML para obtener la información

Tags: java, xml, string, http, split

Estoy programando una integración de mi aplicación con una cámara IP que al realizarle peticiones HTTP me devuelve un fichero XML en el body. Consigo obtener la respuesta de la siguiente manera:

```
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String body = IOUtils.toString(response.body().byteStream(), "UTF-8");
```

En el parámetro `body` tengo un string con todo el contenido del fichero XML. Sin embargo, quiero obtener el valor de sólo algunos de los elementos, es decir, si el contenido de mi parámetro body es:

```
<root>
  <child1>value1<child1>
  <child2>value2<child2>
  <child3>value3<child3>
  <child4>value4<child4>
<root>
```

Quiero obtener los valores del 1 al 4 y poder almacenarlos. He pensado en hacer algo así como un `.split()` pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna librería o funcionalidad específica para estos casos en Java.
Gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te recomiendo que utilices la libreria Xpath.

Podrás encontrar más información en este wiki

> http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Java_y_xpath

Pero te adelanto el ejemplo que puedes encontrar dentro, en las primeras lineas.

Con este XML de ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<espacio>
    <galaxia nombre="Via Lactea">
        <estrella nombre="Sol">
            <planeta nombre="Mercurio" />
            <planeta nombre="Venus" />
            <planeta nombre="Tierra">
                <satelite nombre="Luna" />
            </planeta>
            <planeta nombre="Marte" />
            <planeta nombre="Jupiter">
                <satelite nombre="Io" />
                <satelite nombre="Europa" />
                <satelite nombre="Ganimedes" />
                <satelite nombre="Calisto" />
            </planeta>
            <planeta nombre="Saturno">
                <satelite nombre="Titan" />
                <satelite nombre="Mimas" />
                <satelite nombre="Encelado" />
                <satelite nombre="Tetis" />
                <satelite nombre="Dione" />
                <satelite nombre="Rea" />
                <satelite nombre="Hiperion" />
                <satelite nombre="Japeto" />
            </planeta>
            <planeta nombre="Urano" />
            <planeta nombre="Neptuno" />
            <!-- Lo siento, soy de la vieja escuela -->
            <planeta nombre="Pluton" />
        </estrella>
        <sistema_estelar nombre="Alfa Centauri">
            <estrella nombre="Alfa Centauri A"></estrella>
            <estrella nombre="Alfa Centauri B">
                <planeta nombre="Alfa Centauri Bb"></planeta>
            </estrella>
            <estrella nombre="Proxima Centauri"></estrella>
        </sistema_estelar>
    </galaxia>
    <galaxia nombre="Enana del Can Mayor" />
    <galaxia nombre="Enana de Sagitario" />
    <galaxia nombre="Gran Nube de Magallanes" />
    <galaxia nombre="Enana del Can Mayor" />
    </espacio>
```

Y este código Java, también de ejemplo:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class PruebaXPath {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                // La expresion xpath de busqueda
        String xPathExpression = "//satelite[@nombre='Luna']";

                // Carga del documento xml
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document documento = builder.parse(new File("prueba.xml"));

        // Preparación de xpath
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        // Consultas
        NodeList nodos = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xPathExpression, documento, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i=0;i<nodos.getLength();i++){
            System.out.println(nodos.item(i).getNodeName()+" : " +
                           nodos.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("nombre"));
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos,

David.

Comment: Hola @David.. gracias por tu aporte ! Esa librería tiene muy buena pinta y he estado leyendo la documentación que viene en el enlace. La cuestión es que esto me sirve para obtener los nodos, es decir, es decir, un nodo para cada tag (p. ej. <child1>). Pero me sirve para obtener el valor que hay por medio? Es decil, lo que hay entre <child1> y </child1>

Comment: Si. Solo tienes que utilizar el método text(). Un ejemplo -> Puedes construir la siguiente expresión XPath="/root/child"+n+"[text()]" donde es una variable que contiene el número de hijo que deseas recuperar. Espero que te sea de ayuda. Saludos. David.

Comment: Java es un lenguaje maduro y tiene ya incorporadas librerías para leer adecuadamente archivos XML. Te recomiendo que revises algunos enlaces, sobre todo: (→) [XML Parsing for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK3000), documentación oficial;  (→) [Esta pregunta de Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5059224/5587982); (→) Algún tutorial (no muy antiguo) sobre *Java XML Parser* en Google. No creo que sea necesario recurrir a librerías de terceros en este caso cuando Java trae incorporada esa posibilidad.

Comment: Gracias David.. he solucionado eso e otra forma con nodos.item(i).getTextContent()
@A.Cedano gracias por el aporte.. en este caso no he considerado procesar todo el XML porque sólo me interesan algunos datos. Pero lo tendré en cuenta en futuros desarrollos.